# Dynamically number of buttons after ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have to dynamically create buttons in an Ajax success function. There isn't a fixed number of buttons and
each time the number is different.

I can do it, but not knowing the exact number of elements that will be created, I don't know how to add the correct number of button listener.

AJAX:

```
success : function(data, status, xhr) {
  $("#risultatoLibriCercati").empty();

  var divContent = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    divContent +=
      "<div class='col-sm-2 mt-4'><a data-toggle='modal' data-target='#bookPage" +
      [i] +
      "'><div class='card shadow-sm'><img style='height:250px' src='" +
      data[i].imgLink +
      "' class='img-thumbnail rounded'></div></a></div><div class='modal fade' id='bookPage" +
      [i] +
      "'><div class='modal-dialog'><div class='modal-content'><div class='modal-header text-center'><h4 class='modal-title w-100 dark-grey-text font-weight-bold'>" +
      data[i].titolo +
      "</h4><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-lable='close'>&times;</button></div><div class='mt-4' style='background: url(" +
      data[i].imgLink +
      ") no-repeat;background-size: contain; background-position: center; min-height: 300px;'></div><div class='modal-body mx-4'><div class='md-form'><p class='font-small'>" +
      data[i].autore +
      "</p></div><div class='md-form'><p>" +
      data[i].descrizione +
      "</p></div><div class='text-center mb-3'><button class='btn btn-primary btn-block z-depth-1a' id='aggiungi" +
      [i] +
      "'>Aggiungi a libreria</button><a href='" +
      data[i].isbn13.replace("'", " ") +
      "' target='_blank' style='border:none;text-decoration:none'><img src='https://www.niftybuttons.com/amazon/amazon-button2.png'></a></div></div></div></div></div><input type='hidden' id='categoria" +
      [i] +
      "' value='" +
      data[i].categoria +
      "'><input type='hidden' id='googleID" +
      [i] +
      "' value='" +
      data[i].googleID +
      "'><input type='hidden' id='titolo" +
      [i] +
      "' value='" +
      data[i].titolo.replace("'", " ") +
      "'><input type='hidden' id='descrizione" +
      [i] +
      "' value='" +
      data[i].descrizione.replace("'", " ") +
      "'><input type='hidden' id='autore" +
      [i] +
      "' value='" +
      data[i].autore +
      "'><input type='hidden' id='isbn" +
      [i] +
      "' value='" +
      data[i].isbn13.replace("'", " ") +
      "'><input type='hidden' id='voto" +
      [i] +
      "' value='" +
      data[i].voto +
      "'><input type='hidden' id='imgLink" +
      [i] +
      "' value='" +
      data[i].imgLink +
      "'>";
  }
  $("#risultatoLibriCercati").append(divContent);
}
```

BUTTON ON CLICK LISTENER:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#aggiungi0', function(){                            
  var book = {
    googleID: $("#googleID0").val(),
    titolo: $("#titolo0").val(),
    descrizione: $("#descrizione0").val(),
    isbn13: $("#isbn0").val(),
    voto: $("#voto0").val(),
    imgLink: $("#imgLink0").val(),
    autore: $("#autore0").val(),
    categoria: $("#categoria0").val(),
    userId: getCookie("userId"),
  };    
  $.ajax({
[...]
```

Comment: Could you use a class and add the click listener using the class on the content you just added to the page?

Comment: When I click an a button, I have to pass respective variables to another ajax function. Besides the buttons, I have some <input type="hidden"> each with a different id, so I can get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `class` attribute for those buttons and attach event and index for them as below

```js
var btnIndex = 0;
$('#add').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').append(`<button class="new-btn" data-index=${btnIndex++}>Button test</button>`);
});

$('.container').on('click', '.new-btn', function(e) {
  console.log("clicked" + $(e.target).data("index"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

And passing these values by index into ajax call like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.new-btn', function(e){   
  const idx = $(e.target).data("index");                       
  var book = {
    googleID: $("#googleID" + idx).val(),
    titolo: $("#titolo" + idx).val(),
    descrizione: $("#descrizione" + idx).val(),
    isbn13: $("#isbn" + idx).val(),
    voto: $("#voto" + idx).val(),
    imgLink: $("#imgLink0" + idx).val(),
    autore: $("#autore" + idx).val(),
    categoria: $("#categoria" + idx).val(),
    userId: getCookie("userId"),
  };    
  $.ajax({
[...]
```

Comment: When I click an a button, I have to pass respective variables to another ajax function. Besides the buttons, I have some <input type="hidden"> each with a different id, so I can access their values and pass it to ajax.

Comment: I have updated code. You can add an index as an attribute for dynamically use